# Change domain URL for printURL and createURL

Tags: geoserver, printing, domains, configuration

I have a GeoServer Service enable on my Windows 10 and I install [the extension printing](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/extensions/printing/index.html).

This URL http://localhost:8010/geoserver/pdf/info.json give me this configuration

```
{[...],"printURL":"http://localhost:8010/geoserver/pdf/print.pdf","createURL":"http://localhost:8010/geoserver/pdf/create.json"}
```

I don't know how to change/configure domain name.

I want to change `http://localhost:8010/` by `https://mydomain.org/`

Comment: Why don't you set the main Geoserver domain to that?

Comment: Where can i do that ? In global settings, i put my domain in proxy URL, but doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 3):

I found it.

It's the parameter `proxyBaseUrl` to add in the `Geoserver/data_dir/printing/config.yaml` file.
List of configuration available [here](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/extensions/printing/configuration.html)

```
proxyBaseUrl: https://MY_DOMAIN/geoserver/pdf
```